# Delete a github branch

Tags: git, github, branch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and in Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-in-github)

First of all, I read how to remove a branch, but for some reason is not working on my project: https://github.com/ralcr/sdk.ralcr

When you first enter here you see some files 10 months old in a gh-pages branch. I have no idea how this branch was created and why it's displayed first, but I want to remove it and this is not working

```
Balutas-MacBook-Pro:sdk.ralcr Cristi$ git push origin --delete gh-pages
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I want only the master branch.

Comment: can you do git remote ? maybe your remote is not origin ...

Comment: Seems is not, but which one is my repo? I posted the results below.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution here: https://github.com/matthew-brett/pydagogue/blob/master/gh_delete_master.rst
I couldn't delete the branch because was the default branch. To change it go to Admin and there's a drop down for that.

Answer (score 3):

To delete a remote branch, you must do it like so:

```
git push <remote> :<branch>
# example
git push origin :gh-pages
```

But in your case, origin don't seem to be a remote repo. You should checkout your remote name and use the good one.

```
git remote
```

Also, make sure your remote URL is writable one. Using the `git` protocol is read only, and so you'll need to pickup the `ssh` one. (should also work with the `https` url)

Comment: ls-remote gives me this. Balutas-MacBook-Pro:sdk.ralcr Cristi$ git ls-remote
From git@github.com:ralcr/sdk.ralcr.git
75e1db961aa1d2377e6f7c35542d7ee3a53712a0 HEAD
75e1db961aa1d2377e6f7c35542d7ee3a53712a0 refs/heads/gh-pages
8edf43d1bb60646c5c2f2026bae8c229763d5f98 refs/heads/master

Comment: Oh sorry, it's just `git remote`. `ls-remote` is to list remote branches, tags, and other refs. (edited)

Comment: Ok, git remote gives me something else: ralcr

Comment: But still not working: Balutas-MacBook-Pro:sdk.ralcr Cristi$ git push ralcr :gh-pages
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/gh-pages
To git@github.com:ralcr/sdk.ralcr.git
 ! [remote rejected] gh-pages (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:ralcr/sdk.ralcr.git'

Comment: Oh, you should check out you use a writable url/protocol on your remote if `.git/config` (`git://` protocol is read only). If this is good, then you should checkout you really have write access to your repo. Is it your own?

Comment: Thanks for the clues, it was not the url either, but you helped me find the solution, i'm posting it right now.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `git branch -d <feature-branch>`, it should let you delete a feature branch.

(though normally `git merge <branch-name>` is called before that to merge the branch before deleting it)

To delete the branch on remote:

```
git push origin :<feature-branch>
```